# Return child type from base trait with type class pattern

Tags: scala

I have the following:

```
trait Grabber[A, B] {
  def name: String
  def grab(a: A): Option[B]
}

object Grabber {
  implicit def toBooleanGrabber[A](s: String, f: A => Option[Boolean]) =
    new BooleanGrabber[A] {
      override val name: String = s
      override def grab(a: A): Option[Boolean] = f(a)
    }

  implicit def toDoubleGrabber[A](s: String, f: A => Option[Double]) =
    new DoubleGrabber[A] {
      override val name: String = s
      override def grab(a: A): Option[Double] = f(a)
    }

  implicit def toLongGrabber[A](s: String, f: A => Option[Long]) =
    new LongGrabber[A] {
      override val name: String = s
      override def grab(a: A): Option[Long] = f(a)
    }

  def apply[A, B](
    s: String, 
    f: A => Option[B]
  )(implicit ev: (String, A => Option[B]) => Grabber[A, B]): Grabber[A, B] =
    ev(s, f)
}

trait BooleanGrabber[A] extends Grabber[A, Boolean]
trait DoubleGrabber[A] extends Grabber[A, Double]
trait LongGrabber[A] extends Grabber[A, Long]
```

The `apply` method works fine, but (per its explicit definition) it returns a `Grabber[A, B]`. Is there a way to change the `apply` method's signature (slightly, hopefully) to return the children of `Grabber[A, B]`? For instance, the invocation that uses `toBooleanGrabber` would ideally return a `BooleanGrabber[T]`, rather than a `Grabber[T, Boolean]`.

Comment: May I ask why would you need the concrete type? Meaning, you're abstracting it away for a reason, but now you need to know the underlying type which kind of defeats the purpose I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra type parameter to your `apply` method.

```
def apply[A, B, R](
  s: String, 
  f: A => Option[B]
)(implicit ev: (String, A => Option[B]) => R with Grabber[A, B]): R =
  ev(s, f)
```

Comment: `R <: Grabber[A, B]` perhaps?

Comment: Also possible, but I think less robust, since type parameter bounds are not considered during implicit search.

Comment: Beautiful! (Also, interesting point about bounds during implicit search.)

Comment: You can have both `<:` and `with`. As it is, the compiler won't know it returns a `Grabber` when used generically.